# why we need to create a new object for prototypical inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I am new to the world of Node/Javascript. I have gone through a lot of blogs how inheritance works in javascript, but still I have some confusion.

Here is the example that i setup.

```js
var Mammal = function() {
  this.prop1 = "test1";
}

Mammal.prototype.greet = function(){
  console.log("Hello Word "+ this.prop1);
}


var Animal = function(){
  Mammal.call(this);
  this.prop2 = "test2";
}

Animal.prototype = Mammal.prototype;
//Animal.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);

var a = new Animal();
a.greet();
```

I am not sure between

`Animal.prototype = Mammal.prototype;` and

`Animal.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);`

and even `Animal.prototype = new Mammal();`

What is the right way to setup inheritance ? Both works the similar way.
Any one please help me to understand whats the difference between both.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to set the prototype of Animal to another object, which is created from the Mammal, not set directly to that Mammal. And after setting prototype, also set the constructor of the Animal.

**Why to use another object ?**

Because there are different objects. When you set `Animal.prototype = Mammal.prototype`, this means that you refer to the same object. For the `Animal`, the constructor will be the `Mammal` function which is not right. So for this we create another object, which takes the `Mammal prototypes` properties and functions, and that object is now different. After all, we set the constructor of that object to the `Animal`, so every Animal's constructor will be `Animal` function.

See here with the first approach. Animal and Mammal return the same constructor which is wrong.

```js
var Mammal = function() {
  this.prop1 = "test1";
}

Mammal.prototype.greet = function(){
  console.log("Hello Word "+ this.prop1);
}


var Animal = function(){
  Mammal.call(this);
  this.prop2 = "test2";
}

Animal.prototype = Mammal.prototype;
Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal;

var a = new Animal();
console.log(a.constructor);

var m = new Mammal();
console.log(m.constructor);
```

**This is the right way**

```js
var Mammal = function() {
  this.prop1 = "test1";
}

Mammal.prototype.greet = function(){
  console.log("Hello Word "+ this.prop1);
}


var Animal = function(){
  Mammal.call(this);
  this.prop2 = "test2";
}

Animal.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal;

var a = new Animal();
console.log(a.constructor);

var m = new Mammal();
console.log(m.constructor);
```

Comment: Could you please explain the difference why this is best way to implement inheritance??

Comment: @NiteshGoyal Read the last part

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: Even this works. `Animal.prototype = new Mammal();` . I am not getting a clear picture of all these concepts.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy it will work, because it is a separate object, but in JS, common functions are set in prototype, so I will keep custom functions in each object and don't let to use it

Comment: And because the object can have also properties with their values, why you need to give them to all Animal objects